# Spring AOP for non spring component

Tags: spring, aop, spring-aop

I am writing Spring 4 application with java config. I can use AOP in this project for all spring component. But i can't use it for a normal POJO class.

what is the library I need to add and what is the configuration I need to put in my config file to get this working

Comment: what kind of POJO you need to intercept? post some example(s)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Spring AOP can only be applied to Spring-managed components/beans](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-introduction-spring-defn), not to non-Spring POJOs.

If you want to apply AOP to non-Spring classes you need AspectJ, not a proxy-based "AOP lite" framework like Spring AOP. For more information about how to use AspectJ (which does not need Spring at all) in combination with Spring and how to configure load-time weaving, please read the corresponding part of the [Spring manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-using-aspectj).

Comment: This is what I am looking for. Is there any reference for non-spring AOP implementation. Could you please suggest any reference. Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: I have already provided a link to the Spring AOP manual as a reference. If you would read it, it might help. AspectJ **is** a non-Spring tool you can use it in any Java application without Spring - I always do, I am not a Spring user. The Spring manual just describes how to integrate it into Spring if you are already using the Spring framework anyway. You wrote that you are in a Spring 4 environment, so this is the right reference for you. Otherwise just check out the [AspectJ documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/docs.php) more info on stand-alone usage.