# Spring AOP not working in web-application on tomcat 8

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-aop

I want to use Spring AOP for some logging stuff in my application. I used AOP already in a standalone application and it worked but now with a web-app on a tomcat it's not working.

I have a application-core and a application-web project, where in the core project all the logic happens and the web-project contains only the web-related stuff.

First I tried to add my LoggingAspect class inside my core project, as this did not work I moved it now to the web project but although there it does not work.

Here is my applicationContext.xml which is in folder: /application-web/src/main/webapp

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">

        <!-- Add AspectJ autoproxy support for AOP -->
        <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>


        <!-- Step 3: Add support for component scanning -->
        <context:component-scan base-package="my.foobar"/>

        <!-- Step 4: Add support for conversion, formatting and validation support -->
        <mvc:annotation-driven/>

        <!-- Step 5: Define Spring MVC view resolver -->
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        </bean>
    </beans>
```

And This is my LoggingAspect class which is now here located: application-web/src/main/my.foobar.web/aspects/LoggingAspect

```
    @Aspect
    @Order(1)
    public class LoggingAspect {
        private static final LogHandler LOG = LogHandler.getLogger(LoggingAspect.class);

        @Pointcut("execution(* my.foobar.*.*.*(..))")
        private void completePackage(){}

        @Pointcut("execution(* my.foobar.*.*.get*(..))")
        private void getterMethods(){}

        @Pointcut("execution(* my.foobar.*.*.set*(..))")
        private void setterMethods(){}

        @Pointcut("completePackage() && !(getterMethods() || setterMethods())")
        private void allMethodsExceptGetterAndSetter(){}

        @Around("completePackage()")
        private Object aroundMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint theProceedingJointPoint) throws Throwable{
            LOG.info("around method");
            String method = theProceedingJointPoint.getSignature().getName();
            Object[] arguments = theProceedingJointPoint.getArgs();

            LOG.info("method call: {0}", method);                
            for(Object arg: arguments){
                LOG.info("argument[{0}]", arg);
            }

            Object result = theProceedingJointPoint.proceed();
            return result;
        }

    }
```

I have also added a class to my application-web project

```
@Configurable
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@ComponentScan("my.foobar")
public class ApplicationWebAppConfig {

}
```

What I expect is, that each method which is called will be logged but thats not happen.

Comment: Your aspect needs to be a `@Component` if you want it to be detected by component scan. It also needs to be in the package you specified for component scan.

Comment: I have added the @Component but it did not work either, the aspect is inside the package which i defined in the componentscan. I tried this by breaking some pointcut syntax and here i receive some "Pointcut is not well formated exception" so I guess that my LoggingAspect has been loaded, but somehow its not active?

Comment: During startup I can see: 14:34:20 DEBUG Found AspectJ method: private java.lang.Object my.foobar.aspects.LoggingAspect

Comment: Make your `@Around` advice public, please. Spring needs to find it. If that is not enough, please also make the pointcuts public. And if both is not enough, tell me as a last step after making every method in the aspect public, what happens if you change the `completePackage()` pointcut to `execution(* *(..))`?

Comment: I have changed the pointcuts to public also i tried to use your execution(* *(..)) but also with this change I do not receive any message from my LoggingAspect. Can it be a problem that I am trying this with an embedded tomcat by using gretty?

Comment: When changing the pointcut, did you do that **in addition** to making everything public, as I said? And are your target classes also components? Did you ever get _any_ Spring-AOP aspect running on your Tomcat based on a sample project or so? Probably you have some configuration issue. If all this guesswork (which I dislike anyway) does not help, please edit your question and provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), optimally ready to clone and build with Maven on GitHub.

Comment: I just saw the Gretty remark. I did not even know what it is before I googled it, so I cannot say anything intelligent about it. Maybe keep it simple for starters and start Tomcat manually so as to exclude other possible error sources. Get the simplest possible setup running, then refine and automate it. That way you will find out what is wrong. Debugging with all bells and whistles activated is maybe a bit too ambitious if you are just starting with a new technology.

Comment: I tried it like you described with public pointcuts. My target classes are no components and till now i did not get it working on a tomact. Currently i deployed it, as you suggested,  on a default tomcat 8 installation without gretty stuff but this did not work as well. I will try to make a sample project to see if I get it running in a simple web-project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Al Phaba* wrote:

> I think I figured out my problem. I thought I could use just spring-aop as a standalone feature in my application. I was adding some JSP pages and used for this the first time spring-mvc and during this I saw spring-aop and thought why not using this for some additional measurements of my methods. My sample standalone application worked really good thats why i tried to adapt this to my existing application. But here the problem starts, the **methods** which I want to measure are **not spring related** so as posted from *kriegaex* [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38158365/1082681) this is not working.

Yes, Spring relies on dynamic proxies (by default JDK proxies for classes implementing interfaces, CGLIB proxies for classes not implementing interfaces), and these proxies only work on Spring components because only those get proxied by Spring while wiring the application. AspectJ however weaves directly into the original class's bytecode and can be applied to non-Spring classes as well, as long as they are not already loaded when AspectJ is activated (e.g. JRE classes).

> My solution is a bit disappointing I stopping my feature branch at this point because it currently to much effort to solve it, as I read and you answer suggest I need to switch to AspectJ via LTW.

Well, if your application is working already, if you do it right it is a matter of minutes to change the configuration from Spring AOP to AspectJ as described in the [Spring manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-using-aspectj). I am encouraging you to give it a try, it is really not that hard. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out my problem. I thought I could use just spring-aop as a standalone feature in my application. I was adding some JSP pages and used for this the first time spring-mvc and during this I saw spring-aop and thought why not using this for some additional measurements of my methods. My sample standalone application worked really good thats why i tried to adapt this to my existing application. But here the problem starts, the methods which I want to measure are not spring related so as posted here from @kriegaex here [Spring AOP for non spring component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38043089/spring-aop-for-non-spring-component?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) this is not working

Comment: I got to say I am somewhat disappointed for you cannibalising my comments into your own answer. You found my other answer, fine. But even in my previous comment I explicitly asked you if your target classes are `@Component`s and you said no before I could wake up and tell you that that is the problem. If you already answer your question and steal my points, can you at least describe what you did to solve your problem? Did you e.g. switch from Spring to AspectJ via LTW in your Spring configuration? See, that's exactly why I wanted an MCVE in order to answer your question.

Comment: Sorry to disappoint you, you were really helpful and i am grateful for you answers. I tried everything you described and with those answers and reading some documentation  I came to this conclusion. My solution is a bit disappointing I stopping my feature branch at this point because it currently to much effort to solve it, as I read and you answer suggest I need to switch to AspectJ via LTW. You can post an answer and I will accept it as solution (I dont want to steal anything), I guess you can summarize the topic better than me. So again thank you

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. So now please delete this redundant answer and all our comments with it. The whole question + answer looks cleaner and less redundant then.