# Spring AOP proxy - @CacheEvict is not working in @Entity(from JPA, non-Spring classes)

Tags: spring, jpa, proxy, aop, ehcache

I'm confusing about Spring AOP.

if I put @CacheEvict in the same class with @Cacheable, it works fine.

in Service.java

```
@Service
public class Service {

    @Cacheable(value = "findRecordCache")
    public HealthCheckupRecord getRecordComplete(Long memberId, String checkupDate) {
        ...
    }

    @CacheEvict(value="findRecordCache", allEntries = true) // <-- here
    public void evictTest() {
        // this works okay!
    }
}
```

---

but if I moved @CacheEvict to another class, It doesn't work.

I think the proxy class of Service class points to the Spring Cache manager,
and the proxy class of Entity class also points to the same Spring Cache manager.
Why doesn't it work?

It should be together in the same class?

in Service.java

```
@Service
public class Service {

    @Cacheable(value = "findRecordCache")
    public HealthCheckupRecord getRecordComplete(Long memberId, String checkupDate) {
        ...
    }
}
```

In Entity.java

```
@Entity
public class HealthCheckupRecord extends BaseEntity {
    ...
    @CacheEvict(value="findRecordCache", allEntries = true) // <-- here
    public void update(HealthCheckupRecordDto dto) {
        // it doesn't work!
    }
}
```

---

I want to put a cache in Service.java, and I want to remove a cache in Entity.java.

Comment: `@Entity` is not spring annotation and `@CacheEvict` many not have any effect on the instances of those classes.

Comment: @R.G `@Entity` is from JPA. Did you mean that `@CacheEvict` may not work because the instance of `@Entity` is not from own spring? could you tell me more?

Comment: Disclaimer : I have not tried your code. Spring AOP can only work on Spring Container managed beans. `@CacheEvict` appears to be a Spring AOP magic and should also have the same result.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try AspectJ instead of Spring AOP for caching other instances(not spring bean). I'm not sure of it, so I'm googling how Spring AOP and AspectJ works...

Comment: I found it's possible that Spring AOP can apply to non-Spring classes using AspectJ. https://stackoverflow.com/a/38158365/13885206

Comment: Do read through : https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-using-aspectj