# Aspect AOP not intercepting all methods within pointcut

Tags: exception, apache-kafka, aop, spring-aop, aspect

I have created an aspect for the purpose of error logging and reporting within a microservices system but it is not intercepting all the methods that throw an exception within the pointcut.

```java
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Aspect
@Slf4j
public class LoggingAspect {
    @Pointcut("execution(* *(..)) && within(com.example..*)")
    public void triggerPointcut() {
        System.out.println("triggerPointcut");
    }
    

    @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "triggerPointcut()", throwing = "ex")
    public void logAfterThrowingAllMethods(JoinPoint joinPoint, Throwable ex) {
        System.out.println("****LoggingAspect.logAfterThrowingAllMethods() " + ex);
    }
}
```

For example, when I try to run a method that sends a message to a Kafka topic, a SerializationException occurs which I would like to account for, but the aspect is neither intercepting it nor logging it. I used @Around and @AfterThrowing, @Around has no advices and even though @AfterThrowing does have applicable advices, it still isn't covering everything. The target code below, which fails to be intercepted by the aspect, sits within the pointcut.

```java
@Slf4j
    public class KafkaRunner implements Runnable{
        private final Consumer<String, Object> consumer;
    
        public Listener(Consumer<String, Object> consumer) {
            this.consumer = consumer;
        }
    
        public void start(){
            consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList("topic"));
            try{
                while(true){
                    ConsumerRecords<String, Object> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100));
                    for(ConsumerRecord<String, Object> record : records){
                        System.out.println("Received message: (" + record.key() + ", " + record.value() + ") at offset " + record.offset());
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println("Exception occurred: " + e);
            } finally {
                consumer.close();
            }
        
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please learn [how to ask a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thank you. Specifically, AOP is always an interplay of aspect and target code. It is hard to reason about your situation, being half blind. Or actually, two thirds blind, because Spring configuration also plays a role. I have an educated guess about what might be the problem, but I prefer analysis to speculation.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I have added target code for better context.

Comment: Was anything unclear about "complete"? The classes have no package names or imports. I also do not see your Spring config. Therefore, I have no way of knowing if `KafkaRunner` has been defined as a `@Component` or is instantiated by a `@Bean`method. But that is essential to answer your question. Is that class Spring-managed or not?

Comment: Your code edits are not addressing my questions. I saw you added `@Component` to the aspect, but not to the runner. Therefore, I am assuming that the runner is not spring-managed and therefore the question a [duplicate of similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38158365/1082681), which have been asked here dozens of times before.

Comment: Yes, I had seen similar comments on SO about spring managed beans, but this doesn't seem to be work in this case, as I had previously added the @Component annotation on the KafkaRunner class to get it working, which also failed.

Comment: This is not a discussion forum. Where is your complete, minimal reproducer? Please publish one on GitHub. I cannot debug code I cannot see.